# Rails bootstrap-navbar gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a Rails application using the bootstrap-navbar gem (https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/bootstrap-navbar), but I can't find anywhere in the documentation that says to which file I'm supposed to add the directives to.

I'm not super experience with bootstrap and a lot of the new layout/css frameworks and libraries out there these days, so I'm sure the answer is obvious, but I certainly can't find it.

The example shows how to make a navbar (heres a snippet from https://github.com/bootstrap-ruby/bootstrap-navbar/wiki/Usage-with-Bootstrap-3 ), but I have no idea where to put this:

```
= navbar fixed: :top do
  = navbar_header brand: 'My great app', brand_link: '/home'
  = navbar_collapse do
    = navbar_group class: 'foo', id: 'menu' do
      = navbar_text 'Pick an option:'
      = navbar_item "Home", '/'
      = navbar_item "About Us", '/about-us'
      = navbar_item '/contact' do
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-hand-right
        Contact Us!
```

Thanks for helping a Rails noob!  I've tried putting it in my templates and in helpers, but it doesn't look like actual Ruby, so I'm sure I'm missing something here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is just some pseudo code for the regular erb template language.